# Troubles launching Kestrel

Tags: scala, kestrel

I am try to play with Kestrel 2.4.1 (http://robey.github.io/kestrel/). Unfortunately, it does not launch. I get the following exception when I run the devel.sh script. IOther scripts produce similar exception.

```
Starting kestrel in development mode...
May 17, 2014 2:26:06 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
FATAL: Error in config file: %s
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Position.line
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.Position$class.line(Position.scala:173)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.NoPosition$.line(Position.scala:196)
    at com.twitter.util.Eval$StringCompiler$$anon$1.display(Eval.scala:444)
    at scala.tools.nsc.reporters.AbstractReporter.info0(AbstractReporter.scala:45)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala support for Java 8 is experimental even in 2.11.0, and the github version has the last version of Scala being used as 2.9.2

From: [Kestrel Build File](https://github.com/twitter/kestrel/blob/master/project/Build.scala)

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.2",
```

From: [SCALA 2.11.0 IS NOW AVAILABLE!](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2014/04/21/release-notes-2.11.0.html)

```
The Scala 2.11.x series targets Java 6, with (evolving) experimental support for Java 8. In 2.11.0, Java 8 support is mostly limited to reading Java 8 bytecode and parsing Java 8 source. Stay tuned for more complete (experimental) Java 8 support.
```

I would not expect this to work on Java 8 without having to fix compile issues for 2.10 and 2.11 and then Scala would need better support for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's Logger can not init correctly.
Make sure `queuePath` and `filename` of development.scala are available.